# Jenkins job api json and Rundeck remote url

Tags: jenkins, rundeck

I tried to bind the remote url of Rundeck job with the job api of jenkins as options provider.

So i use the api that give jenkins to call my job with this url `http://localhost:8080/job/my_job/api/json?tree=jobs[name]` who give this

```
{"_class":"org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject","jobs":[{"_class":"org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob","name":"lenormandSeb-patch-2"},{"_class":"org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob","name":"master"},{"_class":"org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob","name":"update%2Fcodesniffer"}]}
```

But when i use this url on rundeck as remote url, only "_class" and "jobs" are showing on select.

Did i miss something on the Rundeck job configuration ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XorDD.png)

thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because Rundeck only admits [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/4.6.1/manual/job-options.html#json-format) kind of format as a remote option. To "understand" other "formats" the quickest way is to develop a custom option plugin that gives options using jq similar to [this one](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/jq-json-logfilter), you can take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/4.6.1/developer/12-option-values-plugins.html#about).